# Homebrew PHP Install Breaks Apache 2.4

Tags: apache, homebrew

When I recently installed PHP56 via Homebrew, Apache would no longer start, with this error in the logs:

> Cannot load /usr/local/opt/php56/libexec/apache2/libphp5.so into server: dlopen(/usr/local/opt/php56/libexec/apache2/libphp5.so, 10): image not found

Note: I'm running Apache 2.4 on Mac El-Capitan.

How can I resolve this error and get Apache running again?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've seen this before.  If you `brew options php56`, it says:

> With the release of macOS Sierra the Apache module is now not built by default. If you want to build it on your system
>   you have to install php with the --with-apache option. See  brew options php56  for more details.

Thus, try uninstalling (`brew uninstall php56`) then reinstalling php56 with the flag `--with-apache` for Apache v2.4.x (`--with-apache22` for Apache 2.2).  Generally, you can check your Apache version by typing in command line: `httpd -v`.

My version is 2.4.18, so I would `brew install php56 --with-apache`, which creates the proper file path `/usr/local/opt/php56/libexec/apache2/libphp5.so`.

Now, it is properly compiled with Apache Handler module.

IMPORTANT: installing php56 with this option appears to also install httpd24.  From a `brew` program stance, this makes sense.  However, this may break your server set up.  If you don't want to use brew's Apache install, do a `brew unlink httpd24` after this.

To see additional brew build options, try `brew options php56`.

Comment: I came back to ask you about some weird apache behavior (binding to a different port than I had configured originally, etc) - and you had already added the note that this *brings apache with it*.  Once I removed the homebrew apache, everything started working properly.  Thank you!

Comment: On Apache/2.4.28 I needed to do `brew install php56 --with-httpd`

Comment: It says: Error: invalid option: --with-httpd
(and the other options also say the same)